# Searching inside the metadata of the PDF documents

Tags: search-engine, google-custom-search, yahoo-api, bing-api, search-engine-api

I have been using Google custom search API for the following task:

- Search for certain keywords with "filetype:pdf"

This works fine as expected, however it only allows searching within the content of the PDF documents. However, I am trying to search within the Metadata of the PDF documents, or within the content stream of the PDF documents.
I have searched a lot and I think there is no way to do this with Google. I was wondering if there is any other search engines that you think I can achieve what I want?

Thank you

Comment: Did you try filetype:pdf intitle:"your PDF keywords"?  May not be what you were looking for.  You might look into using https://scholar.google.com/

Comment: it is possible if only if its indexed

Answer (score 0):

i find this on github but the repo was archived.
It's using differents combinaisont and way,
the script is not updated but i think if you use :

`selenium` `PyPDF2` `PyMuPDF` `json`

and others `regex` techniques by modifing this script,

youn can get there.

https://github.com/TebbaaX/Katana

and with `selenium` `PyPDF2` `PyMuPDF` `bsf4`:

https://pypi.org/project/PyMuPDF/

https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/

https://pypi.org/project/BeautifulSoup/

I don't know if this can help you, but logically you have to scrape files and run analyzes on them to extract the metadata ?